# Connect-PnPOnline from Azure App and Runbook

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, azure-runbook

we have an Azure App Registration and run a PowerShell-Script from a Azure RunBook to sync users from AAD to SharePoint User Profile Store.
The App has approved consent to read users by graph from aad and read/write to SharePoint User-Profiles:

[image]

The PowerShell-Script connects to graph and pnponline by App which is working fine.

```
$serviePrincipalName = 'ZZZ-SPOScript'
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $serviePrincipalName   
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ClientId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://ourtenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Tenant $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ClientId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationID -Thumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
```

We can get all users from aad:

```
$users = Get-MgUser -All -Property "Id,mail,UserPrincipalName,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_ZZZ_townCode,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_ZZZ_costNumber,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_employeeID,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_employeeNumber,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_ZZZ_title,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_ZZZ_office,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_extensionAttribute6,extension_b8fc35d8e8ec45e689d332303177957a_extensionAttribute7"
```

We iterate over all users:

```
foreach($user in $users) {...
```

But when we try to get the user profile properties from SharePoint by calling

```
$fldValue = (Get-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $user.UserPrincipalName).UserProfileProperties."ZZZ-CostNumber";
```

we get **Current user is not a tenant administrator.**

Our Service Principal ZZZ-SPOScript which runs the Script within the RunBook is of course not a tenant admin (and will never be).

So, we added an App Permission entry for the Azure App Registration by /_layouts/15/AppInv.aspx

[image]

with following Permissions to elevate to FullControl

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

But still we get **Current user is not a tenant administrator.** if the Scripts is trying to call
Get-PnPUserProfileProperty

Are we missing something or can this be a bug in pnponline?

Additional finding: As stated [here](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1692#issuecomment-428991347) we should add Full Control permissions for the social features.
So, I upated the permissions to

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
```

But still same error.

Comment: The doco https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpuserprofileproperty?view=sharepoint-ps says _Required Permissions SharePoint: Access to the SharePoint Tenant Administration site_ so it seems like it might need to be tenant administrator.. which is crazy I agree

Comment: You can access to the SharePoint Tenant Administration site with only SharePoint-Adminstrator Role. No need to have Global-Administrator Role. So, may the code is checking, if the logged in user has the global-admin role? What I can see, is that class GetUserProfileProperty inherits PnPAdminCmdlet.  Anyway, currently I am following another approach with PnPSharePointUserProfilesFromAzureActiveDirectory, which is also not working. See: https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/1495

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question.
First, we need proper API-Permission for the App Registration:
[image]

and the correct Full-Control Setting:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" /></AppPermissionRequests>
```

Second, we must connect with the ClientId and the ClientSecret of the App-Registration.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminUrl -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $clientSecret
```

Then Get-PnPUserProfileProperty and Set-PnPUserProfileProperty will work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is simply a typo in the very first string:

```
$serviePrincipalName = 'ZZZ-SPOScript'
```

The correct one should be

```
$servicePrincipalName = 'ZZZ-SPOScript'
```